# proportion confidence intervals

Tags: statistics

Here is a question from my introductory statistics course.

What is the sample size necessary for a two-sided $90\%$ CI for the population proportion $p$ to have a width of $0.2$ when no prior estimate $\hat p$ of $p$ is available?

The answers available are:

- $60$
- $65$
- $70$
- $75$

Apparently option 2 is the correct answer but I cannot figure out why. The method I used is:
$$n=4\cdot Z^2\cdot \hat p\cdot\hat q\cdot\frac{1}{w^2}$$
and i substituted $0.5$ for $p$ and $q$ making the expression a maximum but I'm getting $67.7$ instead of $65$. 
ks

Comment: your question isn't clear. Please add more information [edit].

Comment: in what way is it not clear?                                                                             (n) is the sample size. (p) is the proportion. (w) is the  width , and Z is the z critical value of (0.1/2)= 0.05.

Comment: The sample size can be 1.6, 2.65, 3.7 or 4.75? Should it be an integer number?

Comment: The answers were edited by a mod for some reason. Sorry :(  edited the right answers back

Comment: So originally, $$I=[\mu \pm Z_{\alpha/2}\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}]$$. Then recall that the estimate of p is maximised when $$p=0.5$$, and the corresponding mean and std dev (you probably have a table on this in the manual).

Comment: That's what i did, answer was not the correct one

Comment: Not sure you're interpreting $\sigma$ correctly. See details in my Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of using $\hat p = 1/2$ to get the 'worst' case
(most variable case) is correct.

The relevant value from normal tables is 1.645. This
value cuts 5% of the probability from the upper tail of the standard normal
curve (and -1.645 cuts 5% from the lower tail).

so you
want $1.645\sqrt{(1/2)(1-1/2)/n} = .1.$ This 'margin
of error' is half the width of the CI.

Simplifying somewhat, this becomes $\sqrt{n} = 16.45/2$
or $n =  59.67562,$ so you should go with answer 60.